# Spark - How to take logarithm of every value minus smallest element in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to take logarithm of every value subtracted by the smallest element in a column. For example, if a have a column like:

> score: 1000, 500, 1200, 300

Then I want:

> logged_score: log(700), log(200), log(900), log(0)

I tried with this in Spark data frame:

```
.select(log($"score" - min($"score")).alias("logged_score"))
```

But I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`score`' is not an
>   aggregate function. Wrap '(LOG((`score` - min(`score`))) AS
>   `logged_score`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap '`score`' in
>   first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;

The easiest way to overcome this is by getting the `min($"score")` by collecting it before taking the log value. However, I am trying to avoid doing collect here if there is any better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val minimumValue = df.select(min("score")).first()(0)
df.withColumn("logged_score", log($"score" - lit(minimumValue))).na.fill(0).show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I use similar method with select. One more question, why do you use lit on the third line? It seems to work even without lit.

Comment: I just wanted both to be column types.